# F# assignment to overloaded C# property

Tags: c#, arrays, f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to use a 3rd party C# library in F#. The C# author overloaded a field I am trying to set so that the object itself receives the value. With apologies for the shorthand and incomplete code fragment, the C# looks like this:

```
public class cls1 { public List<cls2> prop1; }
public class cls2 { private double[,] prop2;
                    public object this[int r,int c] 
                      {set {this.prop2[r,c]=value;} }
                  }
```

To set `cls2.prop2`, this works in C#:

`cls1.prop1[0][0, 0] = 0.0`

In F# this fails with the error `"Invalid expression on left of assignment"`:

`cls1.prop1[0][0, 0] <- 0.0`

Can someone offer a hint as to a path forward? Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "overloaded a field" - do you just mean "provided an indexer"?

Comment: @user1620348: To close the question, I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct F# syntax is:

```
   cls1.prop1.[0].[0, 0] <- 0.0
```

From [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx) page on MSDN:

```
You can access array elements by using a dot operator (.) and brackets ([ and ]).
```

Comment: I hate dot array access in F#. :(

Comment: You can use [Array.get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370501), sometimes it gives better function composition :).

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning to an [indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202). There are two ways to refer to an indexed property:

```
x.[0, 0] //array syntax
```

and

```
x.Item(0, 0) //method syntax
```

The former only works if the property is named `Item`, which is the case for any indexed property defined in C#. In F#, however, the name can be arbitrary.